# How to transfer a Blogspot blog to a new domain?

Tags: blog, transfer

I have a blogspot blog, I have purchased a new domain and I want to transfer my old blogspot blog to my new domain.

Is it possible?

If yes then let me know the procedure.

Comment: You should really provide more details.  Are you continuing to use Blogger or are you moving somewhere else like Wordpress?  Did you have a blogspot domain or did you use your own domain name on Blogger?  Perhaps you could show real examples, like your blog URL now and what you want it to be.  That question textbox is *huge*!  It's huge for a reason. Please make good use of it and give us more detail :)

Comment: I want all of my posts of the old blog in the new one.

Comment: You *still* didn't provide the details.  Are you moving to Wordpress, Joomla, Drupal, Bloog, etc?  Where are you moving your blog to?  The procedure will be different depending on where you are moving.  Click the `edit` link below your question so that you can add in more details and make this a better question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're planning on using WordPress to host your new blog (which I would recommend if transitioning from Blogspot), it has a fantastic import feature to grab all of your old posts from Blogspot, and will maintain the permalinks as well.

Tools → Import → Blogger

I tried doing the same thing with Joomla but it was far more cumbersome and error-prone (and required 3rd party extensions that didn't really work very well).